# Vaadin browserframe anchor tags

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have a HTML file in a ZIP file, which I want to be opened in a Browserframe within Vaadin. This works fine and I use a StreamRessource for that. The challange I am facing now is that I want to navigate to an anchor directly.

**So the question is the following:**

How can I navigate to **"xyz.html#test"** instead of **"xyz.html"** only. Setting the filename did not do the trick and I do not see another way.

Thanks!

Florian

Comment: Is the #test in your frame definition? (src tag)

Comment: No. I have not the slightest idea how to do that. I ended up using https://jersey.java.net/ for serving the HTML file (I was using this before) and using an External ressource, With an External Ressource I was able to use "#test". So usuíng an external server (As Vaadin catches "*" a servlet is not possible sadly).